# Фон дрожит при transition

Tags: css, css3, html5

У меня есть два элемента `div`, шириной которых можно управлять с помощью события `click` на `javascript`.

При событии `click` (переключение `className)` или событии `hover`, `background-image`(фоновые изображения), добавленные с помощью псевдоэлемента, дрожат (проверено в `Chrome`, `IE`, `Edge` и `Safari`).

Я посмотрел аналогичные вопросы на `SO` и `Google`, но, похоже, проблема с изменением размера самого фона, но этого я здесь не делал.

```css
section {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1920px;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 700px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
 width: 99%;
 height: 700px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: 1s linear width;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: transparent;
 transform: skew(20deg) translateX(-50%);
 border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.left::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100vw;
 transform: skew(-20deg);
 background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/04/22/38/road-3856796__340.jpg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right {
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
 transform: skew(20deg) translateX(50%);
}

.right::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100vw;
 transform: skew(-20deg);
 background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/taking-a-walk-in-the-woods-picture-id1130258547?s=2048x2048);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right:hover {
 width: 250%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container left"></div>
 <div class="container right"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55183005/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Я оптимизировал код и рассмотрел использование `left/right`, чтобы определить размер элемента, а затем изменил ширину `transition` с `translation`.

```css
section {
  max-width: 1920px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  transition:transform 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}

.left {
  left: -60vw; /*to create the overflow*/
  right: calc(55% + 10px); /*10px distance between both element*/
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.right {
  right: -80vw;
  left: 45%; /*100% - 55% (the right value of .left)*/
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.left::after,
.right::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -40%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -40%;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition:transform 1s linear;
}

.left::after {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/04/22/38/road-3856796__340.jpg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.right::after {
  transform-origin: top;
  background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/taking-a-walk-in-the-woods-picture-id1130258547?s=2048x2048);
}

.right:hover {
  transform: skew(20deg) translateX(-60vw);
}

.right:hover::after {
  transform: skew(-20deg) translateX(60vw);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container left"></div>
  <div class="container right"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Да, бывают такие проблемы с `transition`, спасибо за вопрос с решением.